# How can I link @BeforeEach with @Test method using JUnit extensions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests, junit5

For example, we have 2 classes: `BaseTest` and `Test`; `Test` extends `BaseTest`.

`BaseTest.class` contains 2 methods with `@BeforeEach` annotations.

```
@BeforeEach
  void setUp1() {}

@BeforeEach
  void setUp2() {}
```

`Test.class` contains 2 methods with `@Test` annotations.

```
@Test
void test1() {}

@Test
void test2() {}
```

I want to link the `@BeforeEach` method with `@Test` method, so the `setup1()` would run only before `test1()` and the `setup2()` - only before `test2()`.

I would appreciate a code sample of this task completed using JUnit extensions.

Answer (score 3):

The operative word in `@BeforeEach` is **each**. These methods run before **each** test, and aren't really suitable for the usecase you're describing. If you need such a tight coupling, I'd suggest to move away from JUnit annotations, and just call the setup methods directly:

```
public class BaseTest {
    void setUp1() {}

    void setUp2() {}
}

public class Test extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    void test1() {
        setUp1();
        // test logic
    }

    @Test
    void test2() {
        setUp2();
        // test logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Junit 5 you have a new feature called Nested tests that allows you to have nested classes each with it's own BeforeAll and AfterAll. This requires a little bit of change to your classes hierarchy `BaseTest.class` and `Test.class` but works like a charm :

> @Nested Denotes that the annotated class is a non-static nested test
> class. @BeforeAll and @AfterAll methods cannot be used directly in a
> @Nested test class unless the "per-class" test instance lifecycle is
> used. Such annotations are not inherited.

Comment: This is actually a good idea. Just be careful, because nested tests can quickly get messy.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible like this. There are some other options you could consider:

- Put setup2() and test2() in another test class. Since test1 and test2 do not share the setup ("fixture") they should be in separate classes anyway.
- Remove the @BeforeEach annotation and call the setup methods explicitly at the start of the actual test methods.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put test set up code only in `@BeforeEach` annotated methods. You can put it in the `@Test` method or (perhaps better) in a method called from the `@Test` method.